# Hadoop-2.6.0 Authorization not working for MR jobs

Tags: security, hadoop, authorization, kerberos

- I have configured hadoop-2.6.0 with kerberos security.
- For authorization, i referred the [Documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ServiceLevelAuth.html). But **security.job.submission.protocol.acl** property is not available in the hadoop-policy.xml.
- It seems the property changed into **security.job.client.protocol.acl**. Even though i add any of these property for submitting map reduce jobs, its not working.
- Any user can submit the map reduce job. How to authorize the particular user or group to submit the MR jobs.

**Property**

```
<property>
    <name>security.job.client.protocol.acl</name>
    <value>kumar</value>
    <description>ACL for MRClientProtocol, used by job clients to
    communciate with the MR ApplicationMaster to query job status etc. 
    The ACL is a comma-separated list of user and group names. The user and
    group list is separated by a blank. For e.g. "alice,bob users,wheel".
    A special value of "*" means all users are allowed.</description>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the cloudera Documentation [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/11/migrating-to-mapreduce-2-on-yarn-for-operators/)

It seems that the property **security.job.client.protocol.acl** is for MR1 and for MR2 we can use **security.applicationclient.protocol.acl**.